# How to disable Turbolinks for single page in a shared view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

I have a Javascript, which should work on `$(document).ready` but it won't, because I also have to use turbolinks. 
Is there a way to disable it for this script?
Or at least, is there a way to disable it for the view, I want my script to work on?

---

[image]

Sadly, my Site has to have allways the same layout file, as it is important for the corporate-style.

---

Ok, I found a way, how it should be done, but i don't know how to do it.
In my application.html.erb, I have tp add

```
<body <% if(######) %> data-no-turbolinks <% end %> >
```

The Problem is, I don't know, how to check, if I'm on the Page. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Just change the Javascript to also work on `page:load` as well as `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Is there no way to do it, without? 
For example, there is this `data-no-turbolink` for the body of the shared layout. Can't I give it on specific sites?

Comment: you can create another layout and disable data-no-turbolink in head.

Comment: Instead of disabling turbolink why not fix the javascript?

Comment: Because I have allready tried doing so, and it nearly drove me mental, because it did not want to work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

current_page?(view_path) will check your if statement(not enought rep for comment this)

Answer (score 1):

1) turn off turbolinks - see http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4

2) use new page:load event that turbolinks fires - $(document).on('page:load', your_start_function);, see Rails Jquery doesn't work on other pages - guessing in your case it would be something like

Comment: Thank you, I have found this myself allready. But neither do I want to remove it from every page, nor do I want to edit my script. 
I neew a way to check in my application.html.erb, which page I am visiting right now.