# print line in rails only for a specific page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new in rails and have the following issue:

I have a view that renders from the layout across several pages, it is in fact a part of the header. I want to remove a specific line from the header and hide it only for one page. I have tried to add a condition in the view to check if the page rendered comes from a specific controller/action but it doesn't work. what is the best practice for this case?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep a instance variable in controller action and set is as true. Use this variable to with conditions to include/exclude specific code.

controller action

```
@include = true
```

view

```
if @include.present?
  //place the line which should be excluded
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've asked a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126848/how-to-disable-turbolinks-for-single-page-in-a-shared-view), and you are allready on a good way:
Use a condition like

```
<% if current_page?(view_path)==false %>
 <your line>foobar</your line>
<%end%>
```

Comment: I tried that it crashes for all other page where view_path is not the current page

Answer (score 0):

In the view you can access the controller from params[:controller] so you could have

```
<% if params[:controller] == foo %>
  <p>conditionally shown</p>
<% end %>
```

Its not always best practise to use params directly inside the view though...